# Eror While Executing a dynamic queries in a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I'm executing a dynamic query from a variable but it always says:

> Could not find stored procedure

I have tried to use simpler queries like `set @query = 'select * from [table_name]'` but it gives the same error.

```
CREATE TABLE #test
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(200)
)

DECLARE @TRIGER_NAME VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @V_MAX INT
DECLARE @V_MIN INT
DECLARE @QUERY VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @V_MAX = MAX(id)
FROM #test

SELECT @V_MIN=Min(id)
FROM #test

WHILE @V_MIN <= @V_MAX
BEGIN
    SELECT @TRIGER_NAME = name
    FROM #test
    WHERE id = @V_MIN

    SET @QUERY = 'DROP TRIGGER '+ @TRIGER_NAME;
    EXEC @query

    SET @V_MIN = @V_MIN+1
END
```

In my temporary table is the list of all my trigger name so the expected output I want to get is Command(s) completed successfully. Not 'Could not find stored procedure', because I supposed to executing a dynamic queries not a stored procedure.

Comment: try using the `exec` function `exec(@query)`. `exec` is used to run a stored procedure and `exec(@param)` is used to run a dynamic query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead `EXEC @query` use, `EXEC sp_executesql @query`. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> Executes a Transact-SQL statement or batch that can be reused many
>   times, or one that has been built dynamically. The Transact-SQL
>   statement or batch can contain embedded parameters.

Or if you want to use [EXEC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), change it to:

```
EXEC (@query)
```

From the documentation you have:

> Execute a character string   { EXEC | EXECUTE }
>       ( { @string_variable | [ N ]'tsql_string' } [ + ...n ] )
>       [ AS { LOGIN | USER } = ' name ' ]   [;]

which means your @string_variable or string must be wrapped in `()`.